# How do I simplify my es6 function that combines two arrays based on properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays, an existing collection and a new array.  I want to combine the two in the following way:

- Start with all the elements in the existingConversations
- For each item in the new array, if an element with the same `id` doesn't exist in the existing array, then we'll add it.
- If an item does exist with the same `id` then we replace the existing one only if the value of the `updated` property of the new one is greater than the value of the `updated` property of the existing one.
- If it's not greater than we simply ignore the new element.

We must not modify the arrays passed in and we must return the combined array.

```
function combineConversations(newConversations, existingConversations) {
  const combined = [...existingConversations];
  newConversations.forEach(conversation => {
    const existingConversationIndex = indexOfObject(combined, conversation.id , 'id');
    if (existingConversationIndex && conversation.updated > combined[existingConversationIndex].updated) {
      combined[existingConversationIndex] = conversation;
    } else {
      combined.push(conversation);
    }
  });
  return combined;
}
```

I'd like to know a complete functional approach to doing this.  Is there one?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one line?

Comment: What is `indexOfObject` function?

Comment: Could you add sample input and expected output?

Comment: @toarzaburo, the point would be to follow a full functional approach

Comment: Your own code does not seem to follow the "*If it's not greater than we simply ignore the new element.*" rule

Comment: That's true!  There's a bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
function combineConversations(myArr) {
  return myArr.filter((item1, pos, arr) =>
    arr.map(item2 => item1.id === item2.id && item1.updated === item2.updated).indexOf(true) === pos &&
    arr.every(item2 => !(item1 !== item2 && item1.id === item2.id && item1.updated < item2.updated))
  );
}
combineConversations([...newChat, ...oldChat]);

var oldChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1985, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 1995, data: "au revoir"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2003, data: "bonjour"},
  {id: 4, updated: 2016, data: "hallo"},
];

var newChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1986, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 2004, data: "bye"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2001, data: "bonjour"},
  {id: 5, updated: 2008, data: "vive le sport"}
];

var expected = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1986, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 2004, data: "bye"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2003, data: "bonjour"},
  {id: 4, updated: 2016, data: "hallo"},
  {id: 5, updated: 2008, data: "vive le sport"}
];
```

Thanks @kevin-ternet for your answer.  You got me on the right track!

Comment: I updated the answer to remove duplicates that have the same id and updated properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with a functional approach like this :

```
var oldChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1985, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 1995, data: "au revoir"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2003, data: "bonjour"}
];

var newChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1986, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 2004, data: "bye"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2001, data: "bonjour"},
  {id: 4, updated: 2008, data: "vive le sport"}
];

var result = (oldChat, newChat) => newChat.concat(oldChat).sort((a,b) => a.id-b.id).filter((item, index, arr) => index < arr.length - 1 ? item.id !== arr[index+1].id : true);
console.log(result(oldChat, newChat)); //[ { id: 1, updated: 1986, data: 'coucou' },
//{ id: 2, updated: 2004, data: 'bye' },
//{ id: 3, updated: 2003, data: 'bonjour' },
//{ id: 4, updated: 2008, data: 'vive le sport' } ]
```

Edit : I merged both old and new Arrays and sorted them to obtain adjascent elments having same id and then filtered to keep those who are of unique id or with the latest update

Comment: This is good!  Close.  I wanted to keep the original items in the old array if there were no matches or if new.updated < old.updated.  So I would want id: 3 to be in there too.

Comment: In that case you'd want id: 3 from old or new Array ?

Comment: Old.  So start with the old array, add anything from the new array that didn't already exist (with the same id), if it does exist keep the one with the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach to your problem (I used @kevinternet examples, hope he doesn't mind):

```
var oldChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1985, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 1995, data: "au revoir"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2003, data: "bonjour"}
];

var newChat = [
  {id: 1, updated: 1986, data: "coucou"},
  {id: 2, updated: 2004, data: "bye"},
  {id: 3, updated: 2001, data: "bonjour"},
  {id: 4, updated: 2008, data: "vive le sport"}
];

var intersect = oldChat.reduce((memo, val) => memo.concat(newChat.find(v => val.id === v.id && val.updated < v.updated) || val), []);
var diff = newChat.filter(x => !oldChat.some(y => y.id === x.id));

console.log(intersect.concat(diff));
```

The idea is:

1. Intersect both arrays. It's an special intersection: if the compared elements have the same ID, we must take the more updated so `find` has a special condition, the new element must be more updated than the old, otherwise, we haven't found a correct replacement.
2. We have to deal with the elements that are not common between `oldChat` and `newChat`. Due to the fact that we performed the special intersection from `oldChat` to `newChat` (this guarantees that all the objects in `oldChat` are going to be in the new one), we perform the difference from `newChat` to `oldChat`.
3. Concat the special intersection with the difference in order to get the desired result.

Hope it helps.